# Java - printing all random numbers at the last line of the while loop

Tags: java, random

I have the while loop running and processing properly. When the numbers that the user entered do not match the random number, the code prints out "Sorry ...(and proceeds to explain what the right number is)" each time the user is wrong. However, I cannot get the code to print out those same exact random numbers at the very end of the last loop before it terminates. Any suggestions?

```
   while (counter < 6)
        {
          counter++;
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput = scan.nextInt();
          if (userInput > 60 || userInput < 1)
            System.out.println("Invalid input");

          int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
          if (userInput == randomNumber)
            System.out.println("Congrats, you have won!");
        else
          System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number." + "The winning number is " + randomNumber + ".");
        }
```

The bottom of the code has the winning number, but I want all of those same exact random numbers (which were randomized earlier) to show up at the end of the sixth loop. Also, the order of the user input does not influence the results. If the user chooses 1-13-8-34-56-2 and the computer had come up with 1-8-56-2-14-34…there would still be 5 matching numbers

Comment: Maintain a list of user inputted numbers and random numbers

Comment: I'm trying to do this without array or arraylist., which is what I'm familiar with as of now.

Comment: concatenate the numbers on to a String?

Comment: When you say "the order of the user input does not influence the results", do you mean to say "the game keeps going even after the user has won"?

Answer (score 0):

otherwise you can store them in a string variable after casting them to string by doing this

```
  String randomNums = "";
  randomNums += randomNums +" - "+ String.ValueOf(randomNumber);
```

Comment: I want to do this without array or arraylist.

Comment: otherwise you can store them in a string variable after casting them to string.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be something like this, since you do not want store the numbers in an array or array list, you will have to work with string concatenation.

```
string keepValue="";
while (counter < 6)
        {
      counter++;
      System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
      userInput = scan.nextInt();
      if (userInput > 60 || userInput < 1)
        System.out.println("Invalid input");

      int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
      keepValue=keepValue+randomNumber+"-";


      if (userInput == randomNumber)
        System.out.println("Congrats, you have won!");
    else
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number." + "The 
        winning number is " + randomNumber + ".");
    }
System.out.println(keepValue.substring(0, keepValue.length() - 1));
```

i hope this gives you an idea on how to solve it

Comment: system.out.println(keepValue) should be system.out.println(keepValue.substring(0, keepValue.length() - 1)) else it will print "-" at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is the piece of code,
Just keep concating the random numbers with a string variable

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RandomNumbers{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int counter =0;
        int userInput=0;
        String userEntries="";
        String randomEntries="";
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (counter < 6)
        {
          counter++;
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput = scan.nextInt();
          if (userInput > 60 || userInput < 1)
            System.out.println("Invalid input");

          int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
          if (userInput == randomNumber)
            System.out.println("Congrats, you have won!");
        else
          System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number." + "The winning number is " + randomNumber + ".");
          userEntries+=userInput+ ((counter < 5) ? "-" : "");
          randomEntries+=randomNumber+((counter < 5) ? "-" : "");
        }
        System.out.println(userEntries);
        System.out.println(randomEntries);
     }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 28.
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 39.
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 13.
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 13.
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 8.
Enter a number between 1-60: 
Sorry, you didn't choose the winning number.The winning number is 42.
1-2-3-4-56
28-39-13-13-842
```